# Getting MemoryError while calling np.vstack()

Tags: python, numpy, memory, out-of-memory, ram

I am working on action recognition in UCF Sport dataset . I have extracted all the features . But I need to keep all those features in a numpy array.

```
test = []
train = []
test.append(allhogs[i])
test.append(allhogs[i+1])
vid_descs = []
print allhogs[i]
for el in allhogs[0:i]:
    train.append(el)
for el in allhogs[i+2:]:
   train.append(el)
   feat = s.genfromtxt('/media/prithviraj/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/ucf_sports_feat/' + el)
   # print feat
   k = len(feat)/96
   feat = np.asarray(feat)      
   feat= feat.reshape((k,96))  
   vid_descs.append(feat)
vid_descs = np.asarray(vid_descs)

all_desc = np.vstack(vid_descs)
print all_desc.shape
```

I am getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "t.py", line 39, in <module>
all_desc = np.vstack(vid_descs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 228, in vstack
return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
MemoryError
```

The shape of vid_descs array is (298, 723456, 96). I also saved the vid_descs array and found out that its size is 6 GB. My system's RAM is also 6GB. So should I migrate to a system with higher RAM? Is there any other solution?

Comment: `So should I migrate to a system with higher RAM?` - yes.

Comment: What is the purpose of this `vstack`.  It looks like it is operating on an array.  Is this just a reshape?  Does this work right for a smaller dataset?

Comment: No its more like concatenating . Suppose aa = array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])  and suppose I append  array([[7,8,9],  [10,11,12],  [13,14,15]]) to aa. Then aa will become [[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ],    [ [7,8,9], [ 10,11,12 ], [13,14,15 ] ] ]. But now if I use np.vstack(aa), it will return [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] , [10,11,12],  [13,14,15] ]